# Check if series is convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{n(2n+1)}{({3n^{7}+ln(n)})^{0.5}}$$

For this question, i would like to use comparison test. is it right to use $$\frac{2n^2}{3n^{3.5}}$$ for comparison?

Comment: It's absolutely right and the series is then convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. It is simpler than you think. Note that
$$\frac{n(2n + 1)}{(3n^7 + \ln n)^{1/2}} < \frac{n(2n + 1)}{(3n^7)^{1/2}} = \frac{2n + 1}{\sqrt{3} n^{5/2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3} n^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}n^{5/2}}.$$
Since
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{5/2}}$$
are convergent $p$-series, the series
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{n(2n + 1)}{(3n^7 + \ln n)^{1/2}}$$
converges by the comparison test.

Comment: If we compute the lhs and rhs, we get $3.79053$ and $3.79102$ then very very close. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're right using the asymptotic comparison  but **take care in your calculus**:

$$\dfrac{n(2n+1)}{({3n^{7}+ln(n)})^{0.5}}\sim_\infty \frac{2n^2}{\sqrt3n^{3.5}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt3n^{3/2}}$$
so the series is convergent by comparison with a convergent Riemann series.